# titanium alloy createWebView load html

Tags: android, css, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I seem to have problem when loading html.
without html head and meta tags my page is bigger because of images.
although i have set inline style for them:
    ""

so basically image should be 100% but limited to screen resoultion.
but in reality they are 4-5 time bigger than my screen resolution.

when i set meta tags the images are displayed perfectly fine within bounds of the page:

however font sizes are broken font-size:1px stated inline, shows  something like 14-15px in mobile app

but when i remove meta from html font-size:1px  will be really 1px in mobile app.

any idea's how can i solve this issue. also this only happens on android.. on IOS i don't have such issue with meta  and font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

you html must be responsive you need to add meta tag viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width , initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
```

[Viewport ?](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp)

Comment: since new android patch, viewport that is what causing troubles for font sizes and without it images are too big.

Comment: give us an example of your html to see the problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NPuV1SFy
pasted code here, but already rebuild this app in cordova.